# open a second dialog window from the already opened dialog window

Tags: primefaces

I open a dialog window in my application. After that I would like to open a second dialog from the existing dialog window. The second dialog opens inside the first dialog. The problem arise when the second dialog size is greater than the first one. In that case the second dialog does not appear in the full size but is limited to the size of the first window.

What should I do to display the second dialog window in the whole size?

Best regards,
Javanus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be called a workaround , but...

you always can do something like

```
<p:commandLink value="hide first, show second" onclick="dlg1.hide();dlg2.show();" />
```

(hide first dialog and open the second)

and in the second dialog set `onHide="dlg1.show()"`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help but I should not close the previous dialog.

Comment: b.t.w take a look at the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf  open basic dialog than effects... they seems to be opened fine on top of each other , maybe something in your code?